# How to use $avg to average for a field inside of an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using Mongodb 3.2 and I need to calculate of all fields inside arrays

these is an example of my collection

```
{
  "memTotal" : 33730525659,
  "swapTotal" : 16936129790,
  "queueList" : [
    {
      "usedSlots" : 2,
      "totalSlots" : 8,
      "reservedSlots" : 0,
    },
    {
      "usedSlots" : 2,
      "totalSlots" : 8,
      "reservedSlots" : 0,
    },
    {
      "usedSlots" : 2,
      "totalSlots" : 8,
      "reservedSlots" : 0,
    },
  ],
},
{
  "memTotal" : 33730525659,
  "swapTotal" : 16936129790,
  "queueList" : [
    {
      "usedSlots" : 2,
      "totalSlots" : 8,
      "reservedSlots" : 0,
    },
    {
      "usedSlots" : 2,
      "totalSlots" : 8,
      "reservedSlots" : 0,
    },
    {
      "usedSlots" : 2,
      "totalSlots" : 8,
      "reservedSlots" : 0,
    },
  ],
},
{
  "memTotal" : 33730525659,
  "swapTotal" : 16936129790,
  "queueList" : [
    {
      "usedSlots" : 2,
      "totalSlots" : 8,
      "reservedSlots" : 0,
    },
    {
      "usedSlots" : 2,
      "totalSlots" : 8,
      "reservedSlots" : 0,
    },
    {
      "usedSlots" : 2,
      "totalSlots" : 8,
      "reservedSlots" : 0,
    },
  ],
},
```

I need to calculate average for "queueList.useSlots", "queueList.totalSlots", "queueList.totalSlots", please keep in mind that queueList is an array.

So far what I have done is use aggregation, first I {$unwind: "queueList"}, {$group:{useSlots:{$avg:"queueList.useSlots"}}}

but this return the wrong average :-(

any help would be very appreciated :-) thanks!

Comment: I think you are close to answer try this in `group` `{$group:{"_id":"$_id","useSlots":{"$avg":"queueList.useSlots"}}}`

Comment: What is the expected result here?

Answer (score 3):

Please try the below query.

```
db.memory.aggregate([
{$unwind : "$queueList"}, 
{$group : {_id : "$_id",
   "avgUseSlots" :{$avg :  "$queueList.usedSlots"},
   "avgTotSlots" :{$avg :  "$queueList.totalSlots"},
   "avgReservedSlots" :{$avg :  "$queueList.reservedSlots"}
   }
   }
 ]);
```

**Output:-**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57816e7285ae6441865d83e4"),
    "avgUseSlots" : 2,
    "avgTotSlots" : 8,
    "avgReservedSlots" : 0
}
```